# How can start a activity in the ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mvvm

I am using MVVM to develop a app, but I cannot start activity from AndroidViewModel.

In layout I have a reference to the AndroidViewModel method and inside this method I have the following code:

```
public void startRegister(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplication().getBaseContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
    getApplication().getBaseContext().startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

But this code crashes, how can I open another activity from the AndroidViewModel? Is this the best approach for it?

The error that appear is the following:

> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Thanks

Comment: if the code crash there will be error log, post it with your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't start an activity from the ViewModel, in MVVM the ViewModel shouldn't know anything about the View.

One approach would be:

- Have the method to start the activity in your View(another activity)
- Communicate between the ViewModel and the View via liveData
- Call the start activity method when liveData updates.

Comment: This was my fisrt option but I had the following code: `public void startRegister(){
        register.setValue(true);
        register.setValue(false);
    }` and when this boolean changed then open the code, but I think that this is not a good aproach too, maybe you have anhoter idea that how do it?